# What is the maximum distance Lila Cheney can teleport to?

Tags: comics, marvel, powers, teleportation

We often hear about how Lila Cheney "can teleport across intergalactic distances, but can't easily do short distances".

However, what is her *maximum* teleport distance? Has it ever been mentioned? Has there been a place she went through several "jumps"?

For example, could she theoretically teleport outside the Universe in one jump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Short Answer**

**Lila Cheney has been to the Shi'ar homeworld of Chandilar, believed to be in the Andromeda Galaxy. She has transported herself to Earth and back with the X-men in tow, a distance of 2.5 million light years, each way. This is the farthest known teleportation recorded. If she can teleport this far, then there is no conceivable limit to her range, except for her supposed inability to teleport blind.**

### **Long Answer**

Lila Cheney's mutant power is both ridiculous and staggering in it's implications and applications. Due to the inconsistency in Marvel's space adventures regarding the X-men, we have some difficulties in defining the range of her power. Our best guess is based on her adventures with the X-men and the New Mutants.

Lila's origins are shrouded in mystery and little is known about her childhood. As best as can be determined:

- Her minimum range of transport has been designated at least one light year. Her powers are the activation of a faster than light tachyon field which activates so quickly she cannot stop the teleportation in under one light year's distance.
- She has always claimed she could not teleport blind. I submit this is not quite a true statement. She must have at least tried to teleport blind because she was kidnapped when she was young, supposedly to use her powers for galactic criminal activity.
- How the alien who kidnapped her found her or knew about her mutant ability is unknown. Since he was able to find her, her power must have a unique signature detectable to sufficiently advanced technologies and be unique enough to be sought after.
- After her capture, she was forced to participate in criminal activity until she was able to escape. She claimed her power caused her to appear on a friendly Dyson's sphere where she set up a base of operations. More than likely, she landed a stolen ship there and could then use her powers to return.
- Whenever she teleports across the Earth, she is really teleporting to the Dyson Sphere she used as a base of operations when she escaped from slavery. Her teleportation is so fast, almost no time passes between the trips. The Dyson Sphere is on the far side of the Milky Way galaxy.
- Lila would eventually have a relationship with the Shi'ar and has been to the Shi'ar Imperial Throne-world of Chandilar in the Shi'ar Galaxy. Her time as an intergalactic criminal more than likely caused her to travel through all three of the major nearby galactic empires (Kree, Skrull and Shi'ar).
- Lila Cheney was forced to return to Chandilar in order to bring the X-men back with her. If this is true we can make a case for her maximum known travel distance is at least 2.5 million light years.
- Since no human except [Major Christopher Summers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corsair_%28comics%29), father to Scott Summers [[Cyclops]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclops_%28comics%29) and Alex Summers [[Havoc]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havoc_%28comics%29) has ever piloted a ship to/from the Shi'ar Empire, its exact location is unknown to Earth science. The common consensus is the Shiar Empire is in our nearest galactic neighbor, the Andromeda Galaxy (M31).

**I believe Lila Cheney's power has far greater capacities than she admits to.**

- Given the vast distances and time differentials between locations, even with instantaneous transmissions she is unconsciously calculating for movement between galaxies, stars, solar systems and planetary rotations, without a computer or any other kind of positioning technology.
- Given she can do this there must be some kind of awareness being used to compensate for all of those movements. With this knowledge, **it is conceivable she could transport herself anywhere within the known universe or within the range of her spatial awareness whose true limits are as yet unknown.**

You can also read the [Lila Cheney](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqiHB.jpg) profile in this screenshot from the Marvel Handbook (1982-1983).

Comment: I'm not sure about the awareness part, but it does a good job of showing her limits or lack thereof :)

Answer (score 3):

According to her bio on [aoa](http://aoa.confusticated.com) she has a dormant power for teleportations across the entire universe.
Using this power, Gambit and the X-Ternals were able to travel to another galaxy to retrieve the M'kraan Crystal.

She can teleport herself across vast interstellar distances and has *at least* teleported to another galaxy (in the order of 10 million light-years), no definitive upper-boundary has been established and (like many Marvel characters powers) probably won't be as different writers interpret her powers differently.